# GCP Local SSD dissapeared

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, kubernetes, couchdb

I am running a Kubernetes cluster in GCP and using a local SSD as the persistent disk for a CouchDB service. I've checked today and the disk just disappeared, it is not accessible anymore and thus I can't access my data.

When I run `lsblk` to see the available disks I can't see it anymore. Checking the logs I see the recurrent error:

```
"storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found"
```

Anyone had faced a similar issue? Any hope of recovering my data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, that disk is lost. [GCP local SSDs are not persistent.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#data_persistence)

Answer (score -1):

GCP disks can be persistent, it depends mainly how you define your `StorageClass` objects, when you claim for a new disk and use a StorageClass with the property `reclaimPolicy: Retain`, if you are not using StorageClass (you should be), you also have this option on `PersistentVolume` objects like described here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/